# getting angularjs to work in jsfiddle?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I'm trying to make an angularjs jfiddle for another question, but I can't get it working. Can somebody look at it and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-conroller="MyController">
    Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/><br/>
    <div>
        {{checked}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'my.controllers'
]);

var controllers = app.module('my.controllers', []);
controllers.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.checked = true;
});
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/CosmicAcidGuru/8yTS5/2/)

[fiddle link without external libraries](http://jsfiddle.net/CosmicAcidGuru/8yTS5/4/)

[fiddle link with only ng-animate ext library](http://jsfiddle.net/CosmicAcidGuru/8yTS5/5/)

Can it be that it's because jsfiddle adds a "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/" in front of any external library location? Like when I try to add "ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular-animate.js" then jsfiddle changes it to "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.7/angular-animate.js"

WHY?

Comment: "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available!"

Comment: Looks like fiddle is trying to load 1.3.0 beta unsuccessfully.

Comment: Oh, that's you. Don't load external files if you've set Fiddle to load them for you. :-)

Comment: I removed the external libraries. still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set option `no wrap - in <body>`

You should use:

```
var controllers = angular.module('my.controllers', []);
```

Instead of:

```
var controllers = app.module('my.controllers', []);
```

This fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/NBhn4/1/

**EDIT:**

To work with `ng-animate` you need to include external libraries in correct order and use `No-Library (pure JS)` option or eg. any `jQuery` library:

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NBhn4/175/

Comment: tried it. Your fiddle works because you don't require ngAnimate. But I need that one.

Comment: it works. thanks! And interestingly, it also doesn't add the URL prefix for the libraries anymore now.

Comment: you used ng-conroller (should be controller) in your js but it still works ? how o_O ?

Comment: @nmtuan, it doesn't work :) With `ng-conroller` angular sets values in `$rootScope`. If you change it to `ng-controller`, checkbox will be checked on init (beacuse of `$scope.checked=true` in controller's code. I updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing my answer for those who land on this page , I was used to use **ng-module** directive but in **jsfiddle** after half an hour I realized that **ng-module** is not allowed and you see no error , and when changed that **ng-module** to **ng-app** fiddle worked very well .I just wanted to share this .

```
<div ng-app="appX" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <p>{{greeting}}
  </p>
</div>
```

---

```
var app=angular.module("appX",[]);
console.log(app);
app.controller("appCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.greeting="Hello World";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/furkankatman/trgrjwf1/7/